# Cannot read property 'img' of undefined - Implementing Lightbox

Tags: angular, typescript, lightbox

I am trying to implement a lightbox, however I am getting the following error: Cannot read property 'img' of undefined.

Does anyone know how I can solve?

**Component**

```
img:any;

 ImageInfo(id) {
    var self = this;
    this.Global.refreshToken().subscribe(function (result) {
      self.fileService.getImages(id).then(function (resultado) {
        if (resultado) {
          self.imagMap.set(id,resultado);
          self.img = self.imagMap.set(id,resultado);

          self.items = this.img.map(item =>
            new ImageItem({ src: item.value, thumb: item.value })
          );

          this.basicLightboxExample();
          this.withCustomGalleryConfig();
        }
      }).catch();  
    });
  }
```

**Error on this line**

```
 self.items = this.img.map(item =>
            new ImageItem({ src: item.value, thumb: item.value })
          );
```

**My img**

[image]

Comment: try var self: any;

Comment: My question is also if I am using the map correctly ... I may be calling it wrong, not if everything is correct in this code :(

Comment: I am not sure but `this.img` or `self.img`?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan 
With this I get the post error, self says img.map is not a function

Comment: `self.img` should fix it. Inside the `subscribe` callback you're loosing your reference to the ImageInfo instance as `this`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem started with these following lines:

```
self.imagMap.set(id,resultado);
self.img = self.imagMap.set(id,resultado);
```

can you comment what you get after logging the `self.img`?
What I suspect is `imageMap.set()`, the problem is here. this `set` function returns nothing as per my assumption. as a result if you can `console.log(self.img)` you will get null.

so, do it and check either you are getting null or not.

```
self.imagMap.set(id,resultado);
self.img = self.imagMap.set(id,resultado);
console.log(self.img) // check what you get on console
```

Update:

```
ImageInfo(id) {
    this.Global.refreshToken().subscribe(function (result) {
      this.fileService.getImages(id).then(function (resultado) {
        if (resultado) {
          this.imagMap.set(id, resultado);
          this.img = this.imagMap.set(id, resultado);

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.items = this.img.map(item =>
              new ImageItem({src: item.value, thumb: item.value})
            );

            this.basicLightboxExample();
            this.withCustomGalleryConfig();
          })

        }
      }).catch();
    });
  }
```

You can get rid of the `self` variable and replace the `self` with `this`. It would be better if you attach the entire component.ts file here.

Comment: In the post image, there is what I get on img

Comment: updated my answer. can you attach the entire `.ts` file in the question?